# How to retrieve entire row including all columns in HBase when queried by time range in the scan

Tags: hbase, row, fetch

For a given rowKey scan only returns the columns updated within the time range and rest of the columns of that rowKey are returned as NULL.

How can I get the entire row instead of particular code?

```
Scan scan = new Scan();
scan.setTimeRange(1471710010773L, System.currentTimeMillis());
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont thats possible to get the entire row based on timerange scan.
Hbase works on columns, and not on rows.

Comment: Yes, so what's the solution then. It is appending NULL values for columns which are not fetched.

Answer (score 0):

One of the workaround to deal with such problem is:
1. Apply time range(min,max).
2. Also apply KeyOnlyFilter to fetch only rowKey.
3. Since they will never will retrieved as NULL hence we can then fetch set of records 
   based on these rowKeys which are ultimately filtered based on timerange.

Any better solution?? Please post back!!!